# bootstrap3-datetimepicker: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use this package: https://atmospherejs.com/package/bootstrap3-datetimepicker

I have installed the package above along with one called "moment" but when I try to add it to my input field like this:

time.html:

```
<template name="time">
    <input type='text' class="datetimepicker" />
</template>
```

time.js:

```
Template.time.rendered = function()
{
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ pickDate: false }); // error on this row
}
```

I get the following error:

> Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Does anybody know what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is broken because it does not declare the `moment` dependency. A possible workaround would be to install `moment` package manually, so

```
mrt add moment
```

and then

```
mrt add bootstrap3-datetimepicker
```

**EDIT:** I have just noticed that this solution is actually described [here](https://github.com/tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) by the package author himself.